# WebStorm issue with GoLang struct

Tags: go, webstorm

For some reason, WebStorm (by JetBrains) marks the following simple GoLang struct as error. Specifically, it does not like `string`

```
type Person struct {
    Name string    `json:"name"`
    Address string    `json:"address"`
}
```

But from the looks of it, there is nothing wrong with this? Is there a plugin I am missing in WebStorm?

Comment: It's valid from a Go perspective. I can't comment on the webstorm side of it, sorry :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Go code is correct so as long as there is a GoSDK is defined in WebStorm it should be okay. Make sure that Golang settings are in place.

Click on **WebStorm** -> **Preferences** -> **Languages** **&** **Frameworks** -> **Go** and make sure everything is set there.

Refer to: [Go language (golang.org) support plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5047-go-language-golang-org-support-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

The Go code is correct. As mentioned, you need to enable Go SDK for each separate project.

Also, make sure your WebStorm has [Go Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9568-go) installed or just use [Gogland IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/) (that's like WebStorm but for Go) - it is free now while in beta.